# Holding reference to native class object in JNI

Tags: java, c++, java-native-interface

I am trying to create a c++ class and hold its objects into an array, and reference those c++ objects from java using JNI, since JNI does not provide any mechanism to hold any non primitive type of objects into java.

I have implemented the code as mentioned below but the output is showing me as if multiple objects have got created and i am also receiving a heap error on the second call to create a new native object.

Can anyone look into this?

thanks

**Codes:**

Java class(The function for loading library dll has been defined in LibObj):

```
package org.jnp.pkg004;

import org.jnp.libloader.LibObj;

public class PureCppObjFactory extends LibObj {

    private long cppobjlstsz;

    public PureCppObjFactory() {
        super();
        cppobjlstsz=0;
    }

    public native void newCppObj();

    public native void PrintCppObjDetails(long cppobjlstindex);

}
```

C++ library code:

```
#include "stdafx.h"
#include "stdlib.h"
#include <iostream>
#include <iomanip>
#include <stdio.h>

using namespace std;

#include "org_jnp_pkg004_PureCppObjFactory.h"

class NativeObjClass
{
    private:
        int num_ran;
        int obj_num;
    public:
        static int obj_cnt;
        NativeObjClass()
        {
            obj_cnt++;
            obj_num=obj_cnt;
            num_ran=rand();
            cout<<"Native Object number "<<setfill('0')<<setw(5)<<obj_cnt<<" Random number:"<<num_ran<<endl;    
        }

        int get_obj_num()
        {
            return obj_num;
        }

        int get_num_ran()
        {
            return num_ran;
        }
};

int NativeObjClass::obj_cnt=0;

NativeObjClass *nobj_lst;
long nobj_lst_size=0;

JNIEXPORT void JNICALL Java_org_jnp_pkg004_PureCppObjFactory_newCppObj
  (JNIEnv *env, jobject obj)
{

    jclass thisCls = env->GetObjectClass(obj);
    jfieldID fid=env->GetFieldID(thisCls,"cppobjlstsz","J");    
    NativeObjClass nobj;

    jlong java_lst_sz=env->GetLongField(obj,fid);   

    NativeObjClass *temp_nobj_lst;
    temp_nobj_lst=new NativeObjClass[nobj_lst_size];
    if(nobj_lst_size>0)
    {
        memmove(temp_nobj_lst,nobj_lst,nobj_lst_size);
        delete nobj_lst;
    }   
    nobj_lst_size++;
    nobj_lst=new NativeObjClass[nobj_lst_size];
    if(nobj_lst_size>1)
    {
        memmove(nobj_lst,temp_nobj_lst,nobj_lst_size);
        delete temp_nobj_lst;
    }
    nobj_lst[nobj_lst_size]=nobj;
    java_lst_sz++;

    env->SetLongField(obj,fid,java_lst_sz);

}


JNIEXPORT void JNICALL Java_org_jnp_pkg004_PureCppObjFactory_PrintCppObjDetails
  (JNIEnv *env, jobject obj, jlong indx)
{
    NativeObjClass nobj=nobj_lst[indx];
    cout<<"Retrieved Native Object number "<<setfill('0')<<setw(5)<<nobj.get_obj_num()<<" Random number:"<<nobj.get_num_ran()<<endl;
}
```

Class containing main:

```
package test.jnp.pkg004;

import org.jnp.pkg004.PureCppObjFactory;

public class PureCppObjFactoryTest {

    public static void main(String[] args) {

        PureCppObjFactory pcf=new PureCppObjFactory();
        pcf.newCppObj();
        pcf.PrintCppObjDetails(0);
        pcf.newCppObj();
        //pcf.newCppObj();

    }

}
```

Output:

```
Native Object number 00001 Random number:41
Native Object number 00002 Random number:18467
Retrieved Native Object number 00002 Random number:18467
Native Object number 00003 Random number:6334
Native Object number 00004 Random number:26500
```

**Also getting a heap error popup after this code executes**

Comment: There's so many errors in the C++ code that fixing this is pretty much pointless, I'd recommend learning some more C++ before trying to do the JNI parts. Apart from that, a better approach is to cast native pointers to integrals, and store these integrals in java.

Comment: Hi erik, can u please tell me what are the most important errors i have made in C++ code so that i can try fixing them.

How should casting of native pointers be done and will it work if i compile the same code on 64bit and 32bit windows?

Comment: Hi @Erik, have changed the C++ code as below. Its working fine now. Any other suggestions in it?

Answer (score 5):

Ok, here's a list of issues seen at first glance:

- `using namespace std;` is bad form
- `static int obj_cnt;` isn't threadsafe
- `NativeObjClass *nobj_lst;` should be a static member
- `NativeObjClass *nobj_lst;` should be a std::vector
- `long nobj_lst_size=0;` should be a static member
- `long nobj_lst_size=0;` should be of type `size_t`
- `NativeObjClass nobj;` creates an object - it's not just a reference
- `nobj_lst=(NativeObjClass*)calloc(nobj_lst_size,sizeof(NativeObjClass));` is just plain wrong. Use `new[]` if you have to use your manually managed array, but a `std::vector` would still be better
- `nobj_lst[nobj_lst_size-1]=nobj` copies the object you created
- `NativeObjClass nobj=nobj_lst[indx];` makes a pointless copy of your array object

Consider this approach instead. Note that the below code has not been tested or even compiled, it's just to display the idea.

```
public class CppObject {

    private long handle;

    public CppObject() {
        handle = createNativeObject();
    }

    public void cleanup() {
        deleteNativeObject(handle);
        handle = 0;
    }

    private static native long createNativeObject();
    private static native void deleteNativeObject(long handle);
    private static native void printObjectDetails(long handle);


    public void PrintObjDetails() {
        printObjectDetails(handle);
    }

}




JNIEXPORT jlong JNICALL whatever_createNativeObject(JNIEnv *env, jobject obj) {
    return reinterpret_cast<jlong>(new CppObject());
}

JNIEXPORT void JNICALL whatever_deleteNativeObject(JNIEnv *env, jobject obj, jlong handle) {
    delete reinterpret_cast<CppObject *>(handle);
}

JNIEXPORT void JNICALL printObjectDetails(JNIEnv *env, jobject obj, jlong handle) {
    reinterpret_cast<CppObject *>(handle)->printDetails();
}
```

A java long is 64 bits, so the above code should work fine on both 32 and 64-bit platforms.

Answer (score 0):

```
#include "stdafx.h"
#include "stdlib.h"
#include <iostream>
#include <iomanip>
#include <stdio.h>

using namespace std;

#include "org_jnp_pkg004_PureCppObjFactory.h"

class NativeObjClass
{
    private:
        int num_ran;
        int obj_num;
    public:
        static int obj_cnt;
        NativeObjClass()
        {
            obj_cnt++;
            obj_num=obj_cnt;
            num_ran=rand();
            cout<<"Native Object number "<<setfill('0')<<setw(5)<<obj_cnt<<" Random number:"<<num_ran<<endl;    
        }

        int get_obj_num()
        {
            return obj_num;
        }

        int get_num_ran()
        {
            return num_ran;
        }
};

int NativeObjClass::obj_cnt=0;

NativeObjClass *nobj_lst;
long nobj_lst_size=0;

JNIEXPORT void JNICALL Java_org_jnp_pkg004_PureCppObjFactory_newCppObj
  (JNIEnv *env, jobject obj)
{

    jclass thisCls = env->GetObjectClass(obj);
    jfieldID fid=env->GetFieldID(thisCls,"cppobjlstsz","J");    
    NativeObjClass nobj;    

    jlong java_lst_sz=env->GetLongField(obj,fid);       

    if(nobj_lst_size==0)
    {           
        nobj_lst_size++;
        nobj_lst=(NativeObjClass*)calloc(nobj_lst_size,sizeof(NativeObjClass));     
        nobj_lst[nobj_lst_size-1]=nobj;
    }   
    else
    {
        nobj_lst_size++;
        nobj_lst=(NativeObjClass*)realloc(nobj_lst,nobj_lst_size*sizeof(NativeObjClass));   
        nobj_lst[nobj_lst_size-1]=nobj;
    }   

    java_lst_sz++;
    env->SetLongField(obj,fid,java_lst_sz);

}


JNIEXPORT void JNICALL Java_org_jnp_pkg004_PureCppObjFactory_printCppObjDetails
  (JNIEnv *env, jobject obj, jlong indx)
{
    NativeObjClass nobj=nobj_lst[indx];
    cout<<"Retrieved Native Object number "<<setfill('0')<<setw(5)<<nobj.get_obj_num()<<" Random number:"<<nobj.get_num_ran()<<endl;
}
```